# Escaping json object for kafka axon payload creation

Tags: go

I have been trying to create payload which required json data in escaped format. I can serialize the object but not sure how can I double escaped the same?

Should I just double marshal my object so it escape it?

```
Input: {"new":{"Id":"1","Class":"23"}}

Expected: {\"new\":{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Class\":\"23\"}}
```

Comment: Why would you want those backslashes? Do you *want* invalid JSON?

Comment: Your output shouldn't have backslashes. You generally only need to worry about escaping when writing string literals. Why do you think you need backslashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change last line to `fmt.Printf("%q", string(b))` - this causes the format to be 'escaped string'.

(or if you want to store the escaped string, ```fmt.Sprintf``)

https://play.golang.org/p/uBq3mnys5gE